# doesn't driving query pattern cause N+1 problem?

Tags: orm, spring-batch

In spring batch reference, there is a pattern called `driving query pattern`
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders

I don't know if I misunderstand this pattern right, doesn't `driving query pattern` cause N+1 problem?

It looks like a classic N+1 problem to me, especially they are bad practice in ORM world.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. For each item, the processor will issue another query to grab additional information about the current item.

Comment: Then why spring batch doing that?

Comment: Spring Batch does not do that, you do it if you want using Spring Batch. It is a pattern like any other pattern. Now even if this pattern may introduce a performance issue with large data sets, it could also work perfectly fine for most use cases having medium/small data sets.